# No filter result in synaptic

Tags: 11.10, synaptic

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. And I always depend on synaptic to install new software because I can't remember most of the software packages' names correctly. But Today, my freshly installed Synaptic in my freshly installed Ubuntu 11.10 just don't give any result of the filter.  I can still use search box to find packages, but it not as convenient for sure. So, does anyone here knows a possible solution for that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

try reloading from synaptic and wait for the search index to be rebuild...

Answer (score 0):

Also the same issue may appear in 16.04+ releases. (Re)installing the package apt-xapian-index may solve the problem. [See related Ubuntu forums topic.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318143)